# Shell: check if a subdirectory exists then run command

Tags: bash, directory

I have a directory structure like this:

```
incoming--
         |--sub-P001--|
                      |--func
                      |--anat
         |--sub-P002--|
                      |--anat
         | ....
```

For every subdirectory, I need to check if it contains a subdirectory called `func` and, if it does, run the command `fmriprep-docker`, else run run another command.

I tried this code but it got stuck:

```
    if [ -d $mnt/data/service/incomning/$sub-P*/func ] ; then
        fmriprep-docker run -it ... /mnt/data/service/incoming

    else: 
        fmriprep-docker run -it --anat-only /mnt/data/service/incoming
        fy
    fy
```

Comment: Are `func` and `anat` directories? Do you want to run the command once for each parent folder, i.e. once for `sub-P001` and once for `sub-P002` etc.? Do the commands have to be run with the particular folder as its working directory, or with it as an argument on the command line?

Comment: @Kusalananda command should work on parent (incoming) folder. command fmriprep use a working (incoming) directory mnt/data/service/incoming

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks, how to point directory name in fmriprep?

Comment: What do you mean by "point" and which directory name?

Comment: @Kusalananda is it right to point directory cd "$directory" && fmriprep-docker --fs-license-file /home/service/Documents/sbi-platform/license.txt $directory /mnt/data/service/fmriout participant --fs-no-reconall) in command? i have error: -bash: cd: mnt/data/service/-P*/: No such file or directory

Comment: You used a variable, `$sub`, in your code, so I assumed it was a variable with a value. If you meant just `sub`, then remove the `$` in front of it.  I don't know if your command is otherwise correct since I don't know anything about Docker or the tools you're using.

Comment: @Kusalananda, the issue not in docker command, the issue is how to iterable access to subfolders as i mentioned, because now i can't access /mnt/data/service/incoming/sub-P001 ...  sub-P002 .. sub -P003 - i have an error with -bash: cd: mnt/data/service/-P*/: No such file or directory

Comment: That's because you don't have a variable called `$sub`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check a bunch of pathnames at once in a single `if` statement like that.  Instead, you would have to iterate over the parent folders and test each one whether it contains a `func` directory:

```
for directory in "$mnt"/data/service/incomning/sub-P*/; do
    if [ -d "$directory"/func ]; then
        (cd "$directory" && fmriprep-docker run -it ...)
    else
        (cd "$directory" && fmriprep-docker run -it --anat-only)
    fi
done
```

or something similar (I don't know what this `fmriprep-docker` tool does or how it's used).